# Why did I receive a warning about account blockage?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, post-ban

I tried to delete a question and I received a warning that if you delete question more than once your account is blocked to post more questions. Why did this happen?

Comment: If you delete too many of your questions (especially ones that have negative scores), you can be temporally blocked from asking new questions.

Answer (score 9):

We are trying to ensure that people don't delete their own questions, and then reask, without suffering reputation penalty for downvotes.

See Jeff Atwood's answer in: [I apparently got question-banned for deleting some of my old, zero-upvoted questions. Is there a better way to handle these?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97720/200235)